# Angular ui-router and back button with nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having bad time with nested state, resolve and browser back button.
Below my states configuration, it consists of one abstract state and 2 children state, one to view a profile, 
one to reserve it. The usual flow is opening the profile page, then click on some link and open the request page; this works fine. However if I click the browser back button on *profile-request* page, *ProfileViewController* is executed but profileData is not resolved. 
Is there a way either to reload the previous view as it was (without having to rendering-it again) or force the promise resolution before executing the controller?

```
$stateProvider
  .state('public', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/public.html'
})
.state('public.profile-view', {
    url: '/profile/:slug',
    templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.view.html',
    controller: 'ProfileViewController',
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    resolve: {
      profileData: function($stateParams, Profiles) {
        return Profiles.query({ slug: $stateParams.slug });
      }
    }
})
.state('public.profile-request', {
    url: '/profile/request/:slug',
    templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.request.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'ProfileRequestController',
    resolve: {
      profileData: function($stateParams, Profiles) {
        return Profiles.query({ slug: $stateParams.slug });
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried caching the profileData in Profiles and then in ProfileViewController try to get cached data if it is existing.

Another option is storing profileData in the $rootScope.